# Calculate CAGR monthly in R for 10 years dynamically

Tags: r

my data set is below: lets call it as data_set_final

```
 markets       city    base      year_2018 year_2019 year_2020  
1      AZ      Bell 170104.516  0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959       
2      AZ    Benson   1343.781  0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959      
3      AZ   Buckeye  34155.261  0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959
```

I would like to calculate montly CAGR values and I'm using dplyr package to calculate it

```
cagr_monthly <- data_set_final %>%
  group_by (markets,city) %>%
  mutate (Jan_2018 = base * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + base)  %>%
mutate (Feb_2018 = Jan_2018 * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + Jan_2018) %>%
mutate (Mar_2018 = Feb_2018 * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + Feb_2018) %>%
mutate (Apr_2018 = Mar_2018 * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + Mar_2018) %>%
mutate (May_2018 = Apr_2018 * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + Apr_2018) %>%
mutate (Jun_2018 = May_2018 * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + May_2018) %>%
mutate (Jul_2018 = Jun_2018 * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + Jun_2018) %>%
mutate (Aug_2018 = Jul_2018 * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + Jul_2018) %>%
mutate (Sep_2018 = Aug_2018 * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + Aug_2018) %>%
mutate (Oct_2018 = Sep_2018 * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + Sep_2018) %>%
mutate (Nov_2018 = Oct_2018 * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + Oct_2018) %>%
mutate (Dec_2018 = Nov_2018 * (((1 + year_2018)^(1/12))-1) + Nov_2018) %>%

mutate (Jan_2019 = Dec_2018 * (((1 + year_2019)^(1/12))-1) + Dec_2018) %>%
mutate (Feb_2019 = Jan_2019 * (((1 + year_2019)^(1/12))-1) + Jan_2019) %>%
mutate (Mar_2019 = Feb_2019 * (((1 + year_2019)^(1/12))-1) + Feb_2019) %>%
mutate (Apr_2019 = Mar_2019 * (((1 + year_2019)^(1/12))-1) + Mar_2019) %>%
```

and so on..The output looks like

```
markets  city traffic year_2018 year_2019 year_2020 Jan_2018 Feb_2018 Mar_2018 Apr_2018 May_2018 Jun_2018 Jul_2018 Aug_2018 Sep_2018 Oct_2018
1 AZ      Bell     170105.     0.449     0.402 0.3262959  175440.  180943.  186618.  192472.  198509.  204735.  211157.  217780.  224611.  231656.
2 AZ      Benson     1344.     0.449     0.402 0.3262959    1386.    1429.    1474.    1520.    1568.    1617.    1668.    1720.    1774.    1830.
3 AZ      Buckeye   34155.     0.449     0.402 0.3262959   35227.   36331.   37471.   38646.   39859.   41109.   42398.   43728.   45100.   46514.
```

Is there any efficient way to calculate monthly CAGR since I have data till 2035(sry for not posting all,thought it will be very huge).
I would like to get a new output data_set which includes markets,city and monthly CAGR values instead of adding to data_set_final.
Can someone help me please..

Answer (score 1):

OP is looking for a cumulative product and you can do this in base R using `cumprod` or just `(1+growthRate)^(seq_len(12)/12)` as well.

The middle and longest part of the code is formatting the column names to get the desired output.

```
#calculate cagr
cagr <- do.call(rbind,
    by(dat, paste(dat$markets, dat$city), function(datrow) {
        rates <- datrow[, grepl("^year_", names(datrow))]
        vals <- datrow[,"base"] * c(vapply(rates, function(x) (1+x)^(seq_len(12)/12), numeric(12)))
        data.frame(t(vals))
    })
)

#create the column names for cagr
years <- grep("^year_", names(dat), value=TRUE)
firstYr <- substr(years[1], nchar(years[1])-3, nchar(years[1]))
lastYr <- years[length(years)]
lastYr <- substr(lastYr, nchar(lastYr)-3, nchar(lastYr))
names(cagr) <- format(
    seq(as.Date(paste0(firstYr, "-01-01")), 
        as.Date(paste0(lastYr, "-12-31")), 
        by="1 month"), 
    "%b_%Y")

#output
cagr
```

output:

```
            Jan_2018   Feb_2018   Mar_2018   Apr_2018   May_2018   Jun_2018   Jul_2018   Aug_2018  Sep_2018
AZ Bell    175440.03 180942.897 186618.368 192471.857 198508.946 204735.396 211157.144 217780.318 224611.24
AZ Benson    1385.93   1429.401   1474.236   1520.477   1568.169   1617.356   1668.086   1720.407   1774.37
AZ Buckeye  35226.58  36331.498  37471.075  38646.396  39858.582  41108.790  42398.212  43728.078  45099.66
             Oct_2018   Nov_2018   Dec_2018   Jan_2019   Feb_2019   Mar_2019  Apr_2019   May_2019   Jun_2019
AZ Bell    231656.411 238922.567 246416.634 174961.613 179957.398 185095.831 190380.98 195817.047 201408.330
AZ Benson    1830.025   1887.426   1946.627   1382.151   1421.616   1462.208   1503.96   1546.903   1591.073
AZ Buckeye  46514.257  47973.227  49477.960  35130.517  36133.620  37165.365  38226.57  39318.076  40440.749
             Jul_2019   Aug_2019   Sep_2019   Oct_2019   Nov_2019   Dec_2019   Jan_2020   Feb_2020   Mar_2020
AZ Bell    207159.264 213074.408 219158.450 225416.214 231852.660 238472.889 174154.973 178301.877 182547.526
AZ Benson    1636.504   1683.232   1731.294   1780.729   1831.575   1883.873   1375.779   1408.538   1442.078
AZ Buckeye  41595.478  42783.179  44004.793  45261.289  46553.662  47882.937  34968.552  35801.208  36653.691
             Apr_2020   May_2020   Jun_2020   Jul_2020   Aug_2020   Sep_2020   Oct_2020  Nov_2020   Dec_2020
AZ Bell    186894.270 191344.517 195900.731 200565.436 205341.215 210230.713 215236.638 220361.76 225608.922
AZ Benson    1476.416   1511.571   1547.564   1584.414   1622.142   1660.767   1700.313   1740.80   1782.251
AZ Buckeye  37526.473  38420.038  39334.879  40271.505  41230.433  42212.194  43217.333  44246.41  45299.983
```

data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="markets       city    base      year_2018 year_2019 year_2020  
AZ      Bell 170104.516  0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959       
AZ    Benson   1343.781  0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959      
AZ   Buckeye  34155.261  0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959", header=TRUE)
```

---

Show that soln still works for new data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="markets city tla base year_2018 year_2019 year_2020 year_2021 year_2022 year_2023 year_2024 year_2025 
1 AZ Bell BELL 170104.516 0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 
2 AZ Benson BENS 1343.781 0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 
3 AZ Buckeye BUCK 34155.261 0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25", header=TRUE)
```

cagr output:

```
            Jan_2018   Feb_2018   Mar_2018   Apr_2018   May_2018   Jun_2018   Jul_2018   Aug_2018  Sep_2018   Oct_2018   Nov_2018   Dec_2018   Jan_2019   Feb_2019
AZ Bell    175440.03 180942.897 186618.368 192471.857 198508.946 204735.396 211157.144 217780.318 224611.24 231656.411 238922.567 246416.634 174961.613 179957.398
AZ Benson    1385.93   1429.401   1474.236   1520.477   1568.169   1617.356   1668.086   1720.407   1774.37   1830.025   1887.426   1946.627   1382.151   1421.616
AZ Buckeye  35226.58  36331.498  37471.075  38646.396  39858.582  41108.790  42398.212  43728.078  45099.66  46514.257  47973.227  49477.960  35130.517  36133.620
             Mar_2019  Apr_2019   May_2019   Jun_2019   Jul_2019   Aug_2019   Sep_2019   Oct_2019   Nov_2019   Dec_2019   Jan_2020   Feb_2020   Mar_2020   Apr_2020
AZ Bell    185095.831 190380.98 195817.047 201408.330 207159.264 213074.408 219158.450 225416.214 231852.660 238472.889 174154.973 178301.877 182547.526 186894.270
AZ Benson    1462.208   1503.96   1546.903   1591.073   1636.504   1683.232   1731.294   1780.729   1831.575   1883.873   1375.779   1408.538   1442.078   1476.416
AZ Buckeye  37165.365  38226.57  39318.076  40440.749  41595.478  42783.179  44004.793  45261.289  46553.662  47882.937  34968.552  35801.208  36653.691  37526.473
             May_2020   Jun_2020   Jul_2020   Aug_2020   Sep_2020   Oct_2020  Nov_2020   Dec_2020   Jan_2021   Feb_2021   Mar_2021   Apr_2021   May_2021   Jun_2021
AZ Bell    191344.517 195900.731 200565.436 205341.215 210230.713 215236.638 220361.76 225608.922 173297.253 176549.915 179863.627 183239.535 186678.807 190182.631
AZ Benson    1511.571   1547.564   1584.414   1622.142   1660.767   1700.313   1740.80   1782.251   1369.003   1394.698   1420.875   1447.544   1474.714   1502.393
AZ Buckeye  38420.038  39334.879  40271.505  41230.433  42212.194  43217.333  44246.41  45299.983  34796.330  35449.432  36114.791  36792.640  37483.210  38186.743
             Jul_2021  Aug_2021   Sep_2021   Oct_2021  Nov_2021   Dec_2021   Jan_2022   Feb_2022   Mar_2022   Apr_2022   May_2022   Jun_2022   Jul_2022  Aug_2022
AZ Bell    193752.219 197388.81 201093.648 204868.028 208713.25 212630.645 173297.253 176549.915 179863.627 183239.535 186678.807 190182.631 193752.219 197388.81
AZ Benson    1530.592   1559.32   1588.587   1618.404   1648.78   1679.726   1369.003   1394.698   1420.875   1447.544   1474.714   1502.393   1530.592   1559.32
AZ Buckeye  38903.480  39633.67  40377.564  41135.422  41907.50  42694.076  34796.330  35449.432  36114.791  36792.640  37483.210  38186.743  38903.480  39633.67
             Sep_2022   Oct_2022  Nov_2022   Dec_2022   Jan_2023   Feb_2023   Mar_2023   Apr_2023   May_2023   Jun_2023   Jul_2023  Aug_2023   Sep_2023   Oct_2023
AZ Bell    201093.648 204868.028 208713.25 212630.645 173297.253 176549.915 179863.627 183239.535 186678.807 190182.631 193752.219 197388.81 201093.648 204868.028
AZ Benson    1588.587   1618.404   1648.78   1679.726   1369.003   1394.698   1420.875   1447.544   1474.714   1502.393   1530.592   1559.32   1588.587   1618.404
AZ Buckeye  40377.564  41135.422  41907.50  42694.076  34796.330  35449.432  36114.791  36792.640  37483.210  38186.743  38903.480  39633.67  40377.564  41135.422
            Nov_2023   Dec_2023   Jan_2024   Feb_2024   Mar_2024   Apr_2024   May_2024   Jun_2024   Jul_2024  Aug_2024   Sep_2024   Oct_2024  Nov_2024   Dec_2024
AZ Bell    208713.25 212630.645 173297.253 176549.915 179863.627 183239.535 186678.807 190182.631 193752.219 197388.81 201093.648 204868.028 208713.25 212630.645
AZ Benson    1648.78   1679.726   1369.003   1394.698   1420.875   1447.544   1474.714   1502.393   1530.592   1559.32   1588.587   1618.404   1648.78   1679.726
AZ Buckeye  41907.50  42694.076  34796.330  35449.432  36114.791  36792.640  37483.210  38186.743  38903.480  39633.67  40377.564  41135.422  41907.50  42694.076
             Jan_2025   Feb_2025   Mar_2025   Apr_2025   May_2025   Jun_2025   Jul_2025  Aug_2025   Sep_2025   Oct_2025  Nov_2025   Dec_2025
AZ Bell    173297.253 176549.915 179863.627 183239.535 186678.807 190182.631 193752.219 197388.81 201093.648 204868.028 208713.25 212630.645
AZ Benson    1369.003   1394.698   1420.875   1447.544   1474.714   1502.393   1530.592   1559.32   1588.587   1618.404   1648.78   1679.726
AZ Buckeye  34796.330  35449.432  36114.791  36792.640  37483.210  38186.743  38903.480  39633.67  40377.564  41135.422  41907.50  42694.076
```

Comment: Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match----Got the following error when tried to run cagr function call @chinsoon12

Comment: you can run the `by` function and look at your output. there are some missing years in your actual data as compared to the sample that you posted in OP

Comment: Yeah,Is there any way to overcome this problem.Because my input data doesn't have any missing values.Don't know why some values are missing@chinsoon12

Comment: Need to see the data to propose a fix.

Comment: `markets facility  tla    traffic year_2018 year_2019 year_2020 year_2021 year_2022 year_2023 year_2024 year_2025
1      AZ     Bell BELL 170104.516  0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25
2      AZ   Benson BENS   1343.781  0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25
3      AZ  Buckeye BUCK  34155.261  0.448619 0.4019198 0.3262959      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25      0.25` (my input data)@chinsoon12

Comment: `dat <- data.frame(markets = c("AZ","AZ","AZ"),city = c("Bell","Benson","Buckeye"),base = c(170104.516,1343.781,34155.261),year_2018 = c(0.44,0.44,0.44),year_2019 = c(0.40,0.40,0.40),year_2010 = c(0.32,0.32,0.32),year_2011 = c(0.25,0.25,0.25),year_2012 = c(0.25,0.25,0.25),year_2013 = c(0.25,0.25,0.25))`(input data set)@chinsoon12

Comment: `op <- data.frame(markets = c("AZ","AZ","AZ","AZ","AZ"),city = c("Bell","Bell","Bell","Bell","Bell"),date = c("2018-01-31","2018-02-29","2018-03-31","2018-04-30","2018-05-31"),value = c(175440,180942,186618,192471,198508))` Would like to get output like this @chinsoon12

Comment: your dataset does not have data for years 2014 to 2017? you can edit your post to add in the new dataset

Comment: My data starts from 2018 itself @chinsoon12

Comment: There was typos in your comment containing dat. I have fixed and added to the solution